# how to textscan to read all the lines in a file

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read all the lines in a .m file with the following

```
file_content = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n', 'whitespace', '')
```

but this just returns

```
file_content = 

    {0x1 cell}
```

when actually my file has 224 line. so if i use

```
file_content = textscan(fid,'%s',224,'delimiter','\n')
```

i get all the lines

```
file_content = 

    {224x1 cell}
```

what will be a more proper way to read all the data(mostly strings) in a .m file?
thanks

Comment: what are you asking? define "more proper"

Comment: i am asking what is the correct way of reading the entire content of a file using textscan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not list your needs (are you reading a huge file?, many small files? is speed an issue? what do you really want to do?) I'm giving you the simplest possible answer:

You do this:

```
f = fopen('data.txt');             
g = textscan(f,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(f);
```

remember to close after reading, because otherwise you won't be able to read again.

You can get the first line as g{1}{1}, the second as g{1}{2} and so on.

Here is the matlab documentation for [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) which gives a lot more details.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method that worked for me:

```
fid = fopen('filename','r'); %opening in read mode (default)
inter = textscan(fid,'%[^\n]'); 
lines = inter{1,1};
fclose(fid);
```

This command reads the whole file 'line by line'. for example, I had a text file with 1332 lines, this code creates a variable `inter`  which is a `{1,1 cell}` and `lines` which is a `[1x102944 char]`.

I'm not sure why/how this works (it'd be great if someone else reading this knows how!) but it works for my program.

Comment: '%[^\n]' =>  every character that is not a '\n'

Answer (score 2):

That call to textscan means "read everything up to a \n".

In general your file may have mixed line endings, or none at all and have records separated by ':' or something.